# Expressing boolean operators using logical operators

Tags: logic

From my limited understanding of [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective), it is possible to express the more complex logical operators such as $\operatorname{xnor}$ and $\operatorname{iff}$ as a combination of just a few basic logical operators ($\operatorname{and}$, $\operatorname{or}$, $\operatorname{not}$).

Is it possible to express boolean operators (e.g. equality, subset) as a combination of logical operators too, but that yield only $true$ (tautology) or $false$ (contradiction)?

For example, I could define the $A = B$ operator (set $A$ contains the exact same elements as set $B$) as $(A \land B) \lor (\overline{A \lor B})$, which would yield $true$ when it is true. But it yields *neither $true$ (set of all things) nor $false$ (empty set)* when it is false, and I want it to yield $false$. Is this at all possible? And what about the boolean subset operator?

It's possible I'm combining incompatible concepts (sets, logic, boolean algebra) but please bear with me.

Comment: There is a coorespondence between algebra of sets, boolean algebra and logical conncetives. When we write $A=B$ between sets, we mean : $x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B$. Thus, the $=$ sign correspond with (logical) equivalence : $\leftrightarrow$. And we have that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $(P \land Q) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$ which in turn is : $(P \land Q) \lor \lnot (P \lor Q)$ and this one is *true* exactly when both $P,Q$ are *true* or both *false*. So, why you say that "it yields neither true nor false" ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If I apply that to two unequal sets $P = \{x, y\}$, $Q = \{y, z\}$, it will give me $\{y\}$ which is not the empty set (false, contradiction, as I understand it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're combining different concepts in ways they don't really want to combine.

Your basic problem is that the logical operators (or "connectives" in the jargon of mathematical logic) such as $\land$ *can only be applied between things that have truth values*, and if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then "$A \land B$" doesn't make sense. ("$A\cap B$" does make sense, but produces a set). If you want to start with sets and get a truth value out, at some point in the expression you *need* to have a symbol that applies to sets and gives you a truth value -- such as $\in$ -- and this means your plan of making do with *logical* operations alone is dead in the water as written.

This is not to say there isn't a close connection between set algebra and logic -- indeed, the collection of subsets of some given base sets with operations $\cup$, $\cap$ and complement, and {true,false} with operations $\lor$, $\land$ and $\neg$ are the two prototypical examples of a *boolean algebra*, and you can translate from a formula in propositional logic to an expression in set algebra, and the same laws will hold in each case. However, the set expression will produce a *set* rather than a truth value.

A significant *difference* between the two settings is that in logic, *every* function from a number of truth-valued variables to a truth value can be realized as a Boolean expression, whereas in set algebra there are function from sets to sets that *cannot* be written in this way. One of these is the one you seem to want:
$$ f(A,B) = \begin{cases} U & \text{if $A$ is the same set as $B$} \\
\varnothing & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

The ones you *can* write using Boolean operators are exactly the one where you can determine whether $x\in f(A,B)$ by knowing *only* whether $x\in A$ and whether $x\in B$ (but not, for example, which particular element $x$ is or whether any other elements are in $A$ and/or $B$).

Comment: But isn't the set of everything 'true', and the empty set 'false'? Shouldn't I be able to union sets as if I'm or-ing logical sentences, and get the set of everything when it's undeniably true?

Comment: @Virtlink: No, the universal set is not the same as "true". It _corresponds_ to true under the standard correspondence between logic and set algebra, but that doesn't mean that the two things _are the same_.

Comment: @Virtlink: I have expanded the answer slightly.

Comment: Yes, that function $f$ is the one I'm looking for. If we have $g(A, B) = (A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$ that produces $U$ if A is the same set as B, and something else otherwise; and we think of a function $h(A, B)$ that produces $\varnothing$ if A is not the same as B, and something else otherwise, then can we combine $g$ and $h$ in $f$ to produce $U$ when $A == B$ and $\varnothing$ otherwise? Seems we'd need $f(A, B) = g(A, B) \lor h(A, B)$ in the case $A == B$ but $f(A, B) = g(A, B) \land h(A, B)$ in the case $A \neq B$. Is this the reason it's impossible?

Comment: @Virtlink: Your expression $(A\wedge B)\vee(\not A\wedge \not B)$ still doesn't make sense when $A$ and $B$ are sets. You can write $(A\cap B)\cup(\overline A\cap \overline B)$, which does what you describe here, however. The basic reason why what you want is impossible is that the Boolean operators work element-by-element. Whenever you have a set-algebraic expression $f(A,B)$, there _is no way_ for $x\in f(A,B)$ to depend on which elements _other than $x$_ belong or don't belong to $A$ and $B$. Thus in particular the $h(A,B)$ you specify is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the definition of $x\in (A \star B)$ for any of the operators $\star$ we are considering.  You can notice that they all are defined in the form

$A \star B \iff \forall x\in U,  L$

Where U is the[Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_%28mathematics%29) , and L is some logical expression defined in terms of the logical primitives $(x\in A)$ and $(x\in B)$.

for example

$A \subseteq B\iff ((x\in A) \implies (x\in B))$

Where in this case $L=((x\in A) \implies (x\in B))$.  So essentially there is a duality between logical expressions over $(x\in A)$ and $(x\in B)$, and the set relations on $A$ and $B$.  From there, we notice that we can represent $L$ "as a combination of just a few basic logical operators", and by passing through the duality, represent the set relations as the combination of a few basic dual operations.

For example

$A = B\iff ((x\in A) \iff (x\in B))$

$A = B\iff (((x\in A) \implies (x\in B)) \wedge ((x\in B) \implies (x\in A)))$

$A = B\iff (A\subseteq B \wedge B\subseteq A)$

which I think is the sort of simplification you were asking about.

Comment: Not quite. The subset operator itself is a boolean one, but my question is whether it is at all possible to write all such boolean operators (both equality and subset) as a collection of logical operators or set operations.